# Flip image (scale(-1,1)) when touching limits not working?

Tags: javascript, scale, p5.js, flip

*(Beginner)*
I am creating a game, and I want the images to horizontally flip when they touch the canvas limits, so when I first applied scale(-1,1) it worked fine. After making some changes to the code, it stopped working. I also tried creating a function and call it but the "is not a function" error shows up. Any suggestions?

```
let fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4;
let img1, img2, img3, img4;

function preload() {
  img1 = loadImage("Fishes/fish1.png");
  img2 = loadImage("Fishes/fish2.png");
  img3 = loadImage("Fishes/fish3.png");
  img4 = loadImage("Fishes/fish4.gif");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1920, 1080);

  fish1 = new Fish(400, 150, img1);
  fish2= new Fish(200, 150, img2);
  fish3= new Fish(100, 50, img3);
  fish4= new Fish(200, 150, img4);
}

function draw() {
  background(bg);

  fish1.display();
  fish2.display();
  fish3.display();
  fish4.display();
  fish1.swim1();
  fish2.swim2();
  fish3.swim3();
  fish4.swim4();
  fish1.limits();
  fish2.limits();
  fish3.limits();
  fish4.limits();
}

function flip() {
  scale(-1, 1);
}

class Fish{
  constructor(x, y, inImg) {
    this.img1 = inImg;
    this.img2 = inImg;
    this.img3 = inImg;
    this.img4 = inImg;
    this.x1 = x;
    this.y1 = y;
    this.x2 = x + 1000;
    this.y2 = y + 200;
    this.x3 = x + 100;
    this.y3 = y + 400;
    this.x4 = x + 1000;
    this.y4 = y + 400;
    this.x1direction = random(0, 1);
    this.y1direction = random(0, 1);
    this.x2direction = random(0, 2);
    this.y2direction = random(0, 1);
    this.x3direction = random(0, 2.5);
    this.y3direction = random(0, 3);
    this.x4direction = random(0.5, 2);
    this.y4direction = random(0.3, 1.5);
  }
  display() {
    image(img1, this.x1, this.y1);
    image(img2, this.x2, this.y2);
    image(img3, this.x3, this.y3);
    image(img4, this.x4, this.y4);
  }
  swim1() {
    push();
    translate(this.x1 + px / 80, this.y1 + px / 80);
    if (this.x1direction < 0) {
      //this.img1.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    pop();
    this.x1 += this.x1direction;
    this.y1 += this.y1direction;
  }
  swim2() {
    push();
    translate(this.x2 + px / 80, this.y2 + px / 80);
    if (this.x2direction < 0) {
      //this.img2.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    pop();
    this.x2 += this.x2direction;
    this.y2 += this.y2direction;
  }
  swim3() {
    push();
    translate(this.x3 + px / 80, this.y3 + px / 80);
    if (this.x3direction < 0) {
      //this.img3.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    pop();
    this.x3 += this.x3direction;
    this.y3 += this.y3direction;
  }
  swim4() {
    push();
    translate(this.x4 + px / 80, this.y4 + px / 80);
    if (this.x4direction < 0) {
      //this.img4.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    pop();
    this.x4 += this.x4direction;
    this.y4 += this.y4direction;
  }
  limits() {
    if (this.x1 > width || this.x1 < 0) {
      this.x1direction = -this.x1direction;
    }
    if (this.y1 > height || this.y1 < 0) {
      this.y1direction = -this.y1direction;
    }
    if (this.x2 > width || this.x2 < 0) {
      this.x2direction = -this.x2direction;
    }
    if (this.y2 > height || this.y2 < 0) {
      this.y2direction = -this.y2direction;
    }
    if (this.x3 > width || this.x3 < 0) {
      this.x3direction = -this.x3direction;
    }
    if (this.y3 > height || this.y3 < 0) {
      this.y3direction = -this.y3direction;
    }
    if (this.x4 > width || this.x4 < 0) {
      this.x4direction = -this.x4direction;
    }
    if (this.y4 > height || this.y4 < 0) {
      this.y4direction = -this.y4direction;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know if I successfully answered your question, or if there is something missing or that isn't clear?

Comment: Hey Paul! (I'm new here, is this how I can answer users?) Thank you so much for your answer. I still haven't got around to rework on my code but when I do I'll let you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you were getting an error trying to call your flip function is that you were calling it on the p5.Image objects instead of on the Fish objects:

```
// this is a reference to the current Fish instance
// this.img1 is the field on the Fish instance containing the p5.Image
// So this.img1.flip is not a function because p5.Image has no such function
this.img1.flip();
```

The reason your flipping isn't working is because you aren't drawing the images at the point in your code where you are using `scale(-1, 1)`:

```
  swim1() {
    push();
    translate(this.x1 + px / 80, this.y1 + px / 80);
    if (this.x1direction < 0) {
      // The scale function only effects those elements drawn after it is called
      scale(-1, 1);
    } 
    // Calling pop() resets the drawing state (including all translation and
    // scale transformations) back to the point they were at when the last call
    // to push() was made. So the translation and scale above have no effect
    pop();

    this.x1 += this.x1direction;
    this.y1 += this.y1direction;
  }

  display() {
    // When you are drawing your images, no scaling is applied
    image(img1, this.x1, this.y1);
    image(img2, this.x2, this.y2);
    image(img3, this.x3, this.y3);
    image(img4, this.x4, this.y4);
  }
```

In short it seems like what you are trying to do is flip the actual source image so that the next time you draw it with normal scaling it will appear flipped. However actually implementing it this way would be complicated and less efficient because you would have to make 4 copies of each image (or at least 2 copies, one flipped and one).

A better way to think about this is to think of it as translating to the fishes location, and conditionally scaling, at the point in your code where you are actually drawing the fish. Happily the code looks very similar to what you have now:

```
  swim1() {
    this.x1 += this.x1direction;
    this.y1 += this.y1direction;
  }

  display() {
    push();
    translate(this.x1, this.y1);
    if (this.x1direction < 0) {
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    image(img1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    pop();

    // repeat the above for each of the 4 instances of the fish.
  }
```

There were also a few minor issues such as missing variables `bg` and `px` but I assumed that was just an issue copy and pasting your code to the StackOverflow question.

Here's a working adaptation of your code with a few other tweaks (calls all the swim functions instead of just 1 per fish type, sizes the canvas to the window, uses some random fish images I had lying around, and limits each fish image to 100x100):

```js
let fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4;
let img1, img2, img3, img4;

function preload() {
  img1 = loadImage("https://cdn.glitch.com/0e291b8c-6059-4ca6-a0ae-84e67e1f94e7%2Forange-fish.jpg?v=1613865086898");
  img2 = loadImage("https://cdn.glitch.com/0e291b8c-6059-4ca6-a0ae-84e67e1f94e7%2Fblue-fish.jpg?v=1613865087591");
  img3 = loadImage("https://cdn.glitch.com/0e291b8c-6059-4ca6-a0ae-84e67e1f94e7%2Fpurple-fish.jpg?v=1613865090105");
  img4 = loadImage("https://cdn.glitch.com/0e291b8c-6059-4ca6-a0ae-84e67e1f94e7%2Fwhite-fish.jpg?v=1613865093930");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  fish1 = new Fish(400, 150, img1);
  fish2 = new Fish(200, 150, img2);
  fish3 = new Fish(100, 50, img3);
  fish4 = new Fish(200, 150, img4);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);

  fish1.display();
  fish2.display();
  fish3.display();
  fish4.display();
  fish1.swim();
  fish2.swim();
  fish3.swim();
  fish4.swim();
  fish1.limits();
  fish2.limits();
  fish3.limits();
  fish4.limits();
}

function flip() {
  scale(-1, 1);
}

class Fish{
  constructor(x, y, inImg) {
    this.img1 = inImg;
    this.img2 = inImg;
    this.img3 = inImg;
    this.img4 = inImg;
    this.x1 = x;
    this.y1 = y;
    this.x2 = constrain(x + random(-400, 400), 0, width);
    this.y2 = constrain(y + random(-400, 400), 0, height);
    this.x3 = constrain(x + random(-400, 400), 0, width);
    this.y3 = constrain(y + random(-400, 400), 0, height);
    this.x4 = constrain(x + random(-400, 400), 0, width);
    this.y4 = constrain(y + random(-400, 400), 0, height);
    this.x1direction = random(0, 1);
    this.y1direction = random(0, 1);
    this.x2direction = random(0, 2);
    this.y2direction = random(0, 1);
    this.x3direction = random(0, 2.5);
    this.y3direction = random(0, 3);
    this.x4direction = random(0.5, 2);
    this.y4direction = random(0.3, 1.5);
  }
  display() {
    push();
    translate(this.x1, this.y1);
    if (this.x1direction < 0) {
      //this.img1.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    image(img1, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    pop();
        
    push();
    translate(this.x2, this.y2);
    if (this.x2direction < 0) {
      //this.img2.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    image(img2, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    pop();
        
    push();
    translate(this.x3, this.y3);
    if (this.x3direction < 0) {
      //this.img3.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    image(img3, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    pop();
        
    push();
    translate(this.x4, this.y4);
    if (this.x4direction < 0) {
      //this.img4.flip();
      scale(-1, 1);
    }
    image(img4, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    pop();
  }
    swim() {
        this.swim1();
        this.swim2();
        this.swim3();
        this.swim4();
    }
  swim1() {
    this.x1 += this.x1direction;
    this.y1 += this.y1direction;
  }
  swim2() {
    this.x2 += this.x2direction;
    this.y2 += this.y2direction;
  }
  swim3() {
    this.x3 += this.x3direction;
    this.y3 += this.y3direction;
  }
  swim4() {
    this.x4 += this.x4direction;
    this.y4 += this.y4direction;
  }
  limits() {
    if (this.x1 > width || this.x1 < 0) {
      this.x1direction = -this.x1direction;
    }
    if (this.y1 > height || this.y1 < 0) {
      this.y1direction = -this.y1direction;
    }
    if (this.x2 > width || this.x2 < 0) {
      this.x2direction = -this.x2direction;
    }
    if (this.y2 > height || this.y2 < 0) {
      this.y2direction = -this.y2direction;
    }
    if (this.x3 > width || this.x3 < 0) {
      this.x3direction = -this.x3direction;
    }
    if (this.y3 > height || this.y3 < 0) {
      this.y3direction = -this.y3direction;
    }
    if (this.x4 > width || this.x4 < 0) {
      this.x4direction = -this.x4direction;
    }
    if (this.y4 > height || this.y4 < 0) {
      this.y4direction = -this.y4direction;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Paul! (I'm new here, is this how I can answer users?) Thank you so much for your answer. I still haven't got around to rework on my code but when I do I'll let you know!

Comment: @FilipaViegas Yup, when you comment on somebody's answer or question like this they will get notified and see your reply. I'm glad you saw the answer and I hope it works for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Just rewrote my code with the help of yours and it worked perfectly fine! Thank you so much Paul!